# asp:Image bug onload in IE

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a tag in mypage.aspx:

```
        <asp:Image ID="imgDedoPid"  runat="server"  Height="100%" data-big="" 
                                        ImageAlign="AbsBottom" />
```

and on mypage.aspx.cs i have this call:

```
        Image imgDedoPid.ImageUrl = "Handler1.ashx?file=" + pathImgLoad
        imgDedoPid.Attributes["data-big"] = imgDedoPid.ImageUrl;
        imgDedoPid.Attributes.Add("onload", "lupa();");
```

and the js page is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">       
    function lupa() {                                
        $("#imgDedoPid").mlens(
        {
            imgSrc: $("#imgDedoPid").attr("data-big"), // path of the hi-res version of the image
            lensShape: "circle",            // shape of the lens (circle or square)
            lensSize: 180,              // size of the lens (in px)
            borderSize: 4,              // size of the lens border (in px)
            borderColor: "#fff",            // color of the lens border (#hex)
            borderRadius: 0                 // border radius (optional, only if the shape is square)
        });           

</script>
```

this code works perfectly in google chrome, but does not work in IE9 (The image is already loaded in automatically zoom, but I want this effect: http://mlens.musings.it/)

Can anyone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Is this the IE cache does not fire onload issue?

Comment: Do you even need to call that from the image?   Could you follow their example and just let jquery take care of it? $(document).ready(function() { $("#imgDedoPid").mlens(.....

Comment: Your Javascript syntax appears off. You open a function definition using an open brace but don't close the brace. Is that just an issue with inputting the JS into StackOverflow?